# Raspberry Pi issues with Powerline Ethernet

Tags: raspbian, ethernet

When I connect my Raspberry Pi to a Powerline Ethernet [device](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/powerline/xavb5101.aspx) the Pi doesn't get a network connection.  The Powerline network light blinks on when the Pi boots and then goes off.

Alternatively I've plugged the Pi into a powered hub and the hub to the Powerline device and the Pi doesn't get a network connection. But in this case the Powerline network light stays on.

The Pi is running from a 5v wall adapter.

Other devices (PC, WAP) plugged into the Powerline Ethernet device all work.  The Pi works fine when plugged into a switch.

Does anyone have any idea why the Pi has an issue with connecting to the network via Powerline Ethernet?

Comment: My pi is networked through a powerline adapter, so there's no inherent issue there. Not much consolation for you I'm afraid.

Comment: Me too, have a complete set of Raspberry from the first version to the 2 and anyone is (or was) working fine with Powerline Ethernet. How much Ampere can output your PSU/Charger?

Comment: The USB charger I'm using came with my S4 phone and is specced to output 5V @ 2A.  Can you tell me which brand Powerline adapters you all are using?  - Thanks!